# React: Handle dynamic refs with custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

I'm building an app that relies heavily on animations and I'm having some trouble when working with dynamic refs and custom hooks.

So, I have a custom hook that adds a click event listener, handles an animation and returns a ref.

```js
const usePageChange = () => {
  const node = useRef(null);
  const tl = useMemo(() => gsap.timeline({ paused: true }), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set GSAP timeline
    // omited for the sake of brevety
    return () => {
      tl.kill();
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const set = (ev) => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      tl.play();
    };
    
    const { current } = node;
    current.addEventListener('click', set);

    return () => {
      current.removeEventListener('click', set);
    };
  }, [tl]);

  return node;
};
```

This works fine for `refs` that aren't dynamic:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const elementRef = usePageChange();

  return (
    <div className='slides'>
      <img
        alt='some alt'
        src='/public/someimage.jpg'
        ref={elementRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

But I haven't been able to find a way to do it with dynamic `refs` **without breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)**.

This is what I've tried (simplified), but is obviously not correct. A React Hook cannot be called inside a callback: `useRef(projects.map(() => usePageChange()));`

```js
const Home = () => {
  const projects = useSelector((state) => state.projects.data);

  const elementsRef = useRef(projects.map(() => usePageChange()));

  return (
    <div className='slides'>
      {projects.map((project, i) => (
        <img
          alt={`${project.image_alt}`}
          src={`/public/${project.image_path}`}
          ref={elementsRef[i]}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

What I really need is a way to somehow loop through the projects' length and dynamically call the `usePageChange` hook.

At this point, I don't know if it's better to just add the click event directly to each dynamic element and handle the animation inside the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this, it would make more sense to give each list item state rather than try and maintain some sort of array of children states in the parent component.

```
const ProjectListItem = ({ project }) => {
  const elementRef = usePageChange();

  return (
    <img
      alt={`${project.image_alt}`}
      src={`/public/${project.image_path}`}
      ref={elementRef}
    />
  );
}

const Home = () => {
  const projects = ...;

  return (
    <div className='slides'>
      {projects.map(project => (
        <ProjectListItem project={project} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If that doesn't work for you, you might want to try out the callback form of the `ref` prop:

```
const usePageChange = () => {
  const [node, setNode] = useState(null);

  // ...

  return { node, setNode };
};

const ProjectListItem = ({ project }) => {
  const { setNode } = usePageChange();

  return (
    <img
      alt={`${project.image_alt}`}
      src={`/public/${project.image_path}`}
      ref={setNode}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Handling it on separate components makes much more sense. Thank you for the insight and clarification!